# Is it safe to reference SharedMemory instances straight when using the multiprocessing.shared_memory library in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, numpy, shared-memory

I started using the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` library as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

That is, I create a `numpy` array and write it onto the `SharedMemory` object in one process:

```
import multiprocessing.managers
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

smm = multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager()
smm.start()

sm = smm.SharedMemory(size=a.nbytes)

b = numpy.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=sm.buf)
b[:] = a[:]

print(sm.name)
psm_ad5d71e1
```

And in another process I refer to the `SharedMemory` using its name and access the numpy array that way:

```
import multiprocessing.shared_memory
import numpy
sm = multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="psm_ad5d71e1")
c = numpy.ndarray((6,), dtype=numpy.int64, buffer=sm.buf)

print(c)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

So far so good. But in my example, when the `numpy` array grows far larger (GBs in size) the interpreter keeps dying (as in it just quits without throwing any exceptions) when I dereference the `numpy` array created from the `SharedMemory` object, that is, the `print(c)` line.

After a long time of experimenting I realized if I referred to the `MemoryObject` straight everything worked as expected:

```
import multiprocessing.managers
import numpy
import pickle

a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

smm = multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager()
smm.start()

sm = smm.SharedMemory(size=a.nbytes)

b = numpy.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=sm.buf)

b[:] = a[:]

with open('sm.pcl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(sm, f)
```

And in the other process I do this instead:

```
import multiprocessing.shared_memory
import numpy
import pickle

with open('sm.pcl', 'rb') as f:
    sm = pickle.load(f)
c = numpy.ndarray((6,), dtype=numpy.int64, buffer=sm.buf)

print(c)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

(In my actual example I don't `pickle` the `SharedMemory` object manually, that's done automatically as I pass the `SharedMemory` object in the arguments to the separate process.)

So my question is simply, is this safe? Or am I using the library in an unintended (and unsafe) way?

If I were to guess, it should be safe as the `SharedMemory` object is a pointer in itself. So I reckon it should be the same thing to refer to the `SharedMemory` object itself, or reference it through its `name` attribute using the `SharedMemory` function...

But I would love to have someone who *actually* knows comment! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run the failing code inside Python inside a debugger.  Then you can find out where it is crashing.  Maybe it's just running out of memory?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of it failing? Eg where it's exiting without a traceback.